# How to make the timeseries axis ticks and labels match the data points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I've managed to bypass this issue by manually setting my xticks.
However, I would like to understand the reason behind this 'issue'.

I have the following data:

[image]

As you can see, I've calculated the average basket for our weekly campaign.
However, if I try plotting it, the first couple dates are changed.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))

plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(avg_basket_pbm["trunc_usage_date"]), avg_basket_pbm["average_base_spend"], label="Monday Coupon Users")
plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(avg_basket_reg["TRUNC(EV.EFFECTIVE_DAY,'DD')"]), avg_basket_reg["average_base_spend"], label="Regular Coupon Users")
# plt.xticks(pd.to_datetime(avg_basket_pbm["trunc_usage_date"],format="%Y-%m-%d"), labels = avg_basket_pbm["trunc_usage_date"])
plt.title("Average Basket", weight = "bold", fontsize=14)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

This seems to only influence the first couple dates, the latter ones remain unchanged.

Reproducible Example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = ['2021-10-11 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-18 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-25 00:00:00',
 '2021-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2021-11-08 00:00:00',
 '2021-11-15 00:00:00',
 '2021-11-22 00:00:00']


stamps = pd.to_datetime(dates)
vals = np.random.random(7)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
plt.plot(stamps, vals)
```

Comment: If you are plotting dates, the ticks are spaced aesthetically, not labelling your data.  Some of your dates happen to lie on the aesthetic boundary, but that is a co-incindence (try setting the 4th date to `2021-11-02` and you will see the ticks dont' change).

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib does not try to match the ticks exactly to your data because in most situations that just looks bad. To illustrate, I adapted your example and added just four datapoints and forced the xticks to match the data:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = ['2021-10-11 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-18 00:00:00',
 '2021-10-25 00:00:00',
 '2021-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2021-11-08 00:00:00',
 '2021-11-09 00:00:00', # added
 '2021-11-10 00:00:00', # added
 '2021-11-11 00:00:00', # added
 '2021-11-12 00:00:00', # added
 '2021-11-15 00:00:00',
 '2021-11-22 00:00:00']


stamps = pd.to_datetime(dates)
vals = np.random.random(11)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
plt.xticks(stamps, labels = dates)
plt.plot(stamps, vals)
```

[image]

The tick labels overlap and are unreadable. If you comment the `plt.xticks` line out, matplotlib is allowed to "do its own thing" and put the ticks where it considers it "reasonable". In this specific case, it appears to be "weekly, starting from the 1st of the month". If you have a different opinion/algorithm for what you consider "reasonable" tick mark positions, then you have to place them manually.

Comment: That does make sense.
However, wouldn't increasing the figure size allow plt to plot the 'original' ticks?

Comment: You can have thousands of data points.  You don't want them all ticked in general.

Answer (score 2):

- The correct way to plot a `pandas.DataFrame` is with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), which uses `matplotlib` as the default backend
- `pandas` adjusts the tick locations and labels to prevent crowding the axis
- Specify the `xticks=` parameter to have the date ticks and labels match the dates in the dataframe, but this can lead to crowding the axis so that it become unreadable.
- **Tested in `python 3.9.7`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.5.0`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates1 = ['2021-10-11 00:00:00', '2021-10-18 00:00:00', '2021-10-25 00:00:00', '2021-11-01 00:00:00', '2021-11-08 00:00:00', '2021-12-15 00:00:00', '2021-12-22 00:00:00']
dates2 = ['2021-10-12 00:00:00', '2021-10-19 00:00:00', '2021-10-26 00:00:00', '2021-11-02 00:00:00', '2021-11-09 00:00:00', '2021-12-16 00:00:00', '2021-12-23 00:00:00']
np.random.seed(365)
vals1 = np.random.random(7) * 200
vals2 = np.random.random(7) * 200

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date1': dates1, 'val1': vals1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date2': dates2, 'val2': vals2})

# convert the colmun to a datetime dtype
df1.date1 = pd.to_datetime(df1.date1).dt.date
df2.date2 = pd.to_datetime(df2.date2).dt.date

# plot the dataframe
ax = df1.plot(x='date1', marker='o', figsize=(12, 5))
df2.plot(x='date2', marker='o', ax=ax)

ax.set_title("Average Basket", weight="bold", fontsize=14)
```

[image]

- Specifying `xticks=df1.date1`, or `xticks=df2.date2`, all of the dates from one DataFrame will be on the x-axis.

  - The dates in the two DataFrames are not the same.

```py
ax = df1.plot(x='date1', marker='o', figsize=(12, 5))
df2.plot(x='date2', marker='o', ax=ax, xticks=df1.date1, rot=90, grid=True)

ax.set_title("Average Basket", weight="bold", fontsize=14)
```

[image]

- Combine the dates from both DataFrames to use as `xticks`

```py
# combine the dates to be used for xticks
xticks = df1.date1.tolist() + df2.date2.tolist()

# plot the dataframe
ax = df1.plot(x='date1', marker='o', figsize=(12, 5))
df2.plot(x='date2', marker='o', ax=ax, xticks=xticks, rot=90, grid=True)

ax.set_title("Average Basket", weight="bold", fontsize=14)
```

[image]