# Plot line Kind doesn't take all values in x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm calculating the count of files everyday and i want to plot it as a line , here is my dataframe:

```
,DAY_DEPOSE,counts
0,01-Jan,2
1,05-Jan,10
2,06-Jan,4
3,07-Jan,12
4,10-Jan,14
5,11-Jan,22
6,12-Jan,411
7,13-Jan,183
8,14-Jan,100
9,15-Jan,59
10,16-Jan,20
11,17-Jan,227
12,18-Jan,119
13,19-Jan,236
14,20-Jan,190
15,21-Jan,589
16,22-Jan,1542
17,23-Jan,1567
18,24-Jan,1802
19,25-Jan,1824
20,26-Jan,663
```

but when creating the plotLine i see that it's skipping/or not showing some values from x-axis
here is my code

```
out2=data4.groupby('DAY_DEPOSE').size().reset_index(name='counts')
out2.set_index('DAY_DEPOSE', inplace=True)
fig5=plt.figure()
ax=out2.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20,18))
```

and this is the figure that i get
[image]

As u can see , it took only 5 values (01-Jan/11-Jan/16-Jan/21-Jan/26-Jan)
anyone can help

Comment: It took all values, but tick labelled only 5 of them.

Comment: Those are the tick marks, evenly dividing up your time axis; by default you do not get a separate tick mark per entry

Comment: is there a way to separate tickes marks?

Comment: Do you mean to [set and label an x-tick at each position where a data point is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70172877/8881141)? This might be quite busy depending on your dataset.